# How to delete rows with "~" character inside the data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lyis.png)

I am trying to get rid of all rows that contain "~"....
ive looked all over the internet with no results.

any help would be great!
thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the code and attempts so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrix to create a logical vector to keep only rows having no `-` elements

```
res <- df1[rowSums(df1=="-")==0,]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, '-', 4), col2 = c('-', 1, 3, 2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```